# Django: Remove all data from every table (but keep the tables themselves)

Tags: django

I'm trying to sync data between two django installations (production and testing).  I'm doing this using `./manage.py dumpdata --natural` on production, then `./manage.py loaddata` into a freshly `syncdb`'ed database on testing.

Everything was working fine until I added a new custom permission.  The production `syncdb` loaded this new permission in a different order (with different primary key) than a new `syncdb` on an empty database does.  Consequently, it gets a different ID.  So despite using natural keys, when I attempt to load the data, I'm getting this error when the first out-of-order permission object is loaded:

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_permission_content_type_id_codename_key"
```

The easiest way I can think of to fix this is to remove all data from every table in the testing installation -- that is, to use `syncdb` just to create tables, and not to also load initial data.  But `syncdb` doesn't let you skip the initial data/signals step.  Short of enumerating every model or table name explicitly, how can I remove all initial data after calling `syncdb`?  Or is there a way to create just the empty tables without using `syncdb`?

`./manage.py flush` isn't what I'm after -- it reloads initial data and triggers syncdb signals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the help for flush command (I'm using Django 1.3.1) the SQL that is executed is the same SQL obtained from `./manage.py sqlflush`, and then the initial data fixtures is reinstalled.

```
$ python manage.py help flush 
Usage: manage.py flush [options]

Executes ``sqlflush`` on the current database.
```

To get the same data wiping capabilities minus the fixture loading you can obtain the SQL by calling `./manage.py sqlflush` and then execute that SQL using Django's built-in support for executing arbitrary SQL:

```
from django.core.management import call_command, setup_environ
from your_django_project import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from django.db import connection
from StringIO import StringIO

def main():
    # 'call' manage.py flush and capture its outputted sql
    command_output = StringIO()
    call_command("sqlflush", stdout=command_output)

    command_output.seek(0)
    flush_sql = command_output.read()

    # execute the sql
    # from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(flush_sql)

    print "db has been reset"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This has the added benefit that you can modify the SQL from `./manage.py sqlflush` before execution to avoid wiping tables that you might want to leave intact.

Also, according to [the current Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-flush), in Django 1.5 a new parameter `./manage.py flush --no-initial-data` will reset the data and not load the initial data fixture.

Answer (score 0):

For Django <= 1.4, you can use the [`reset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#reset-appname-appname) management command.

```
./manage.py sqlreset myapp1 myapp2
```

Comment: reset is deprecated, as the docs you link mention; but it requires you to enumerate each app, which I want to avoid.  Flush is its replacement; but it loads initial data.

Comment: deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it. If you don't want to enumerate the app names, I think you'll have to write your own management command.

Comment: It's removed in 1.5. unfortunately it doesn't look like there is a way to flush a single app anymore :(